# After upgrading to java 21: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration.propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I recently upgraded my spring boot project to java 21. Post the upgrade I am facing the below issue:

```java
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration.propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108) ~[spring-context-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:183) ~[spring-context-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:144) ~[spring-context-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:120) ~[spring-context-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:428) ~[spring-context-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:289) ~[spring-context-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:349) ~[spring-context-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:118) ~[spring-context-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:775) ~[spring-context-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:597) ~[spring-context-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:753) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:455) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:323) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1342) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1331) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at com.company.core.app.Application.main(Application.java:30) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid value type for attribute 'factoryBeanObjectType': java.lang.String
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getTypeForFactoryBeanFromAttributes(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:86) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:838) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isTypeMatch(AbstractBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:573) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:532) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:247) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:240) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:230) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:183) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:158) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
```

My best guess is that there is some dependency version mismatch, but I can't decipher which dependency to drill down on. My dependency tree looks like the following:

```xml
 +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:6.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:6.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:6.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:6.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:6.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:6.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:6.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:jar:6.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.micrometer:micrometer-observation:jar:1.12.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- io.micrometer:micrometer-commons:jar:1.12.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:6.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:6.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:3.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:3.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:3.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.4.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.4.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.22.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:2.0.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:3.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.15.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.15.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.15.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.15.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.15.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.15.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:3.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:10.1.16:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:10.1.16:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:10.1.16:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:6.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:3.2.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:3.2.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:3.2.0:test
[INFO] |  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.8.0:test
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:4.0.1:test
[INFO] |  |  \- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:2.1.2:test
[INFO] |  +- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.5.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:2.5.0:test
[INFO] |  |     \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:9.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.24.2:test
[INFO] |  |  \- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.14.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.awaitility:awaitility:jar:4.2.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest:jar:2.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:jar:5.10.1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.10.1:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.3.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.10.1:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:jar:5.10.1:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.10.1:test
[INFO] |  |     \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.10.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:5.7.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.14.10:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:3.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:jar:5.7.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.1:test
[INFO] |  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:6.1.1:test
[INFO] |  \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.9.1:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools:jar:3.2.0:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:3.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:3.2.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.10.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.projectlombok:lombok:jar:1.18.30:compile
[INFO] +- org.modelmapper.extensions:modelmapper-jackson:jar:2.4.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.modelmapper:modelmapper:jar:2.4.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.22.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.22.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb:jar:3.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-sync:jar:4.11.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.mongodb:bson:jar:4.11.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-core:jar:4.11.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.mongodb:bson-record-codec:jar:4.11.1:runtime
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:jar:4.2.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:6.1.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:3.2.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign:jar:4.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter:jar:4.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-context:jar:4.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-rsa:jar:1.0.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk18on:jar:1.73:compile
[INFO] |  |        \- org.bouncycastle:bcutil-jdk18on:jar:1.73:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-openfeign-core:jar:4.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:3.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.9.20.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.github.openfeign.form:feign-form-spring:jar:3.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- io.github.openfeign.form:feign-form:jar:3.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-commons:jar:4.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.github.openfeign:feign-core:jar:12.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.github.openfeign:feign-slf4j:jar:12.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-ext-jdk18on:jar:1.77:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:jar:3.2.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-resource-server:jar:6.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-core:jar:6.2.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-jose:jar:6.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt:jar:9.24.4:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.github.stephenc.jcip:jcip-annotations:jar:1.0-1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:5.7.10:compile
[INFO] +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:2.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:8.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.5.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.6.0:compile
[INFO] +- io.springfox:springfox-boot-starter:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-oas:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-annotations:jar:2.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-models:jar:2.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.springfox:springfox-spi:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.springfox:springfox-schema:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.springfox:springfox-core:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.springfox:springfox-spring-web:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.github.classgraph:classgraph:jar:4.8.83:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.springfox:springfox-spring-webmvc:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.springfox:springfox-spring-webflux:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger-common:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.mapstruct:mapstruct:jar:1.3.1.Final:runtime
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-data-rest:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-bean-validators:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.swagger:swagger-annotations:jar:1.5.20:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.swagger:swagger-models:jar:1.5.20:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:2.0.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-core:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-metadata:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- io.github.openfeign:feign-okhttp:jar:11.10:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:jar:4.12.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:jar:1.9.20:compile
[INFO] |        +- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:jar:1.9.20:compile
[INFO] |        |  \- org.jetbrains:annotations:jar:13.0:compile
[INFO] |        \- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:jar:1.9.20:compile
[INFO] +- com.squareup.okio:okio:jar:3.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.squareup.okio:okio-jvm:jar:3.4.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:jar:1.9.20:compile
[INFO] +- com.microsoft.azure:applicationinsights-web-auto:jar:2.5.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.opencsv:opencsv:jar:5.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.13.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-text:jar:1.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:jar:4.4:compile
[INFO] +- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO] +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.11.0:compile
[INFO] \- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.5.1:compile
```

Comment: Without a full pom file and also other information like which maven version you are using etc. it is more or less impossible to even guess... What me astonishes is the things like plexus-utils which looks completely wrong...

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I upgraded to spring boot `3.2.0` and forgot to upgrade spring cloud to `2023.0.0`.

I think you have the same issue since you have `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign:jar:4.0.4` instead of `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign:jar:4.1.0`.